# Normal line to the border of a set

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> $D=\left\{(x, y): x^{2}+y^{2}<4, x y>\sqrt{3}, x>0\right\}$. Find the normal line to $\partial D$ that passes through $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3 / 2})$.

I don't really know how to approach this problem. I've found the derivates of the circle for the tangent line, but I don't think it's correct, because I have to consider the hyperbola too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point $\left(\sqrt2,\sqrt{\frac32}\right)$ belongs indeed to the boundary of $D$. But it is an interior point of the circle. On the other hand, it is a point of the hyperbola $xy=\sqrt3$. So, consider the function$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt3}x.$$Then $f'(x)=-\frac{\sqrt3}{x^2}$ and $f'\left(\sqrt2\right)=-\frac{\sqrt3}2$. So, the slope of the tangent at $\left(\sqrt2,\sqrt{\frac32}\right)$ is $-\frac{\sqrt3}2$ and therefore the slope of the normal line at that point is $\frac2{\sqrt3}$. So, the normal line is$$y=\frac2{\sqrt3}\left(x-\sqrt2\right)+\sqrt{\frac32}.\tag1$$

---

You can reach the same conclusion using the gradient. The hyperbola is the level curve $xy=\sqrt3$. So, let $g(x,y)=xy$. Then$$\nabla g\left(\sqrt2,\sqrt{\frac32}\right)=\left(\sqrt{\frac32},\sqrt2\right)$$and this vector has the same direction as the normal line. Therefore, the slope of the normal line is $\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{3/2}}=\frac2{\sqrt3}$. And this is all you need to deduce that the normal line is the line $(1)$.

[image]